# Refreshing Magento checkout step

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have added functionality to Payment method step, which is related to shipping address, if shipping address changes, then Payment method HTML content must be reloaded. I tried to add JavaScript to Billing and Shipping step, but my backend requires that Shipping address is saved to work. So If I add my own JavaScript after onclick="shipping.save();" in shipping.phtml, it is never called.

Is there way to refresh step HTML every time step is viewed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible but not with pure JS (there is not ajax callbacks available to  reload a step by a single click)

You'll need to overload the `OnepageController` from `Mage_Checkout`. In this class you'll see that each step saveAction contains the logic to refresh/display the next step.

For example, in the `saveShippingAction()` of `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController` you can see :

```
[...]
if (!isset($result['error'])) {
    $result['goto_section'] = 'shipping_method';
    $result['update_section'] = array(
        'name' => 'shipping-method',
        'html' => $this->_getShippingMethodsHtml()
    );
}
[...]
```

The part `update_section` is the one to tell magento to force-refresh the step.

You should be able to adapt this to your needs.

Comment: HI I have a issue related to above , but your solution has given me a direction to track the issue in my project and with that i been able to do this.  thanks